# Need to know if phone is FAR or CLOSE to user's ear while in a call

Tags: android, sensors, proximity

I want to track the phone's position while the user is in call. **I don't want to register the proximity sensor for it because it's redundant and I don't want to count that sensor battery consumption on me**, the system uses the proximity anyway when a call starts.

My question is how can I get the position ("far"/"close" in Android logs terminology) of the phone relative to the user's ear?

Thanks
Bush

Comment: once you register a sensor, the system counts the sensor-time on your app (no matter it already opened by other app - checked and verified), and sensors are pretty heavy consumers.. I want my app's battery consumption percentage to as low as I can.

Comment: Unless the standard telephone app has an API to allow you access to its proximity sensor data, I don't think you can get the information without registering a listener...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the proximity sensor is the best way to check the distance from the user's face.

However, if you're willing to come up with some good algorithms, you could try using the accelerometer and the microphone. However, the microphone may not be available to two apps at once.

If the user's device is touching their face, there will be less accelerometer movement that varies from one direction to another. However, if the phone is held away, there will be some shaking. And if there is no change in the accelerometer readings at all, it is likely lying on a desk, and the user is talking on loudspeaker or using a headset.

Comment: thanks Raghav, But I don't need the distance, I only need to know when Android consider the distance as 'far' or 'close', Android do this with/without me.. I didn't dig into their algorithm and I don't want to.. I just want to trust them and give me a notification when they considering the distance as far and close..

Comment: Then you can just use the proximity sensor. It's battery consumption isn't very high. If this isn't an option, you should find a way to check if the screen is currently on. Since android switches it off during calls when the phone is close, checking that should give you the location.